# How do you validate phone number in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to validate phone number that allows numeric and symbols + - () 
how can i do so in asp.net?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter valid Phone number" ControlToValidate="TxtNo" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Do you mean US phone numbers only? In my opinion use an input mask to force data entry in a specific manner rather than trying to figure out what the user entered.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter valid Phone number" ControlToValidate="TxtNo" ValidationExpression="^[01]?[- .]?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})[- .]?\d{3}[- .]?\d{4}$" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

with the expression that should specify the format that needs to be validated. You can choose one from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/197101/ASP-net-validation-of-phone-number) and specify it in the validation expression above

Comment: Yes correct. I know that have to use validation expression. if i use ValidationExpression="^(\(|\d| |-|\))*$" than it validates for numeric and symbols like - ( ) but not for + symbol.

Comment: you can add the + at the start as an optional input

Comment: something like [01+]?

Answer (score 1):

```
ValidationExpression= "^([0-9\(\)\/\+ \-]*)$"

<asp:TextBox ID="TxtNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" 
runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter valid Phone number" 
ControlToValidate="TxtNo" 
ValidationExpression= "^([0-9\(\)\/\+ \-]*)$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this validation expression

```
^([\(]{1}[0-9]{3}[\)]{1}[\.| |\-]{0,1}|^[0-9]{3}[\.|\-| ]?)?[0-9]{3}(\.|\-| )?[0-9]{4}$
```