# TextBox for mobile number validation in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, validation

How can i customize a `RadRumeric TextBox` for mobile number validation. am using a `RadRumeric TextBox` for validating numbers. while using the same for mobile number validation it allows `.` how can i avoid this?

```
 <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtphone" Skin="WebBlue" runat="server" ValidationGroup="contact" Width="90%" MaxLength="32" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="0">
           <NumberFormat DecimalDigits="0" DecimalSeparator ="."/>
 </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
 <span class="warning">*</span><br />
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator25" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtphone" CssClass="warning" ErrorMessage="Enter contact no." ValidationGroup="contact"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

when i give `DecimalSeparator =""` will throws error

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you validate phone number in asp.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18585613/how-do-you-validate-phone-number-in-asp-net)

Comment: @ Codexer : these reference will shows validation of asp:testboxes. my question was about telerik RadNemeric textbox

Comment: What is the exact number format that you want to be entered? Also is there a reason you are using RadNumberTextBox instead of something like RadMaskedTextBox or RegExpTextBoxSetting?

Comment: something like 9876543210 only 10 digit number

Answer (score 0):

Try using the RadMastedTextBox for validating your numbers as it was designed for this sort of thing:

```
<telerik:RadMaskedTextBox ID="txtphone" runat="server" Label="mobile phone #: " Width="250px" SelectionOnFocus="CaretToBeginning" Mask="(###) ###-####" TextMode="SingleLine" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for the numbers which begin from 0,+91 or 9... etc.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ph" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regx" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ph" ErrorMessage="*Enter valid Mobile Number"  ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^[0][0-9]{10}|^[+91][0-9]{12}|[0-9]{10}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```